# How to set Cloud Tasks dispatch when load balancer and GAE are combined

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, dispatch

I'm using Cloud Tasks from GAE now.
Also, by setting GAE as the backend of the load balancer, the following processing is tested.
`batch-service` is a service I created.

1. Request to `/job/test_cron` from local machine
2. go to Load balancer
3. go to GAE's service（`batch-servise`） from Load balancer
4. Create Cloud Task and request `/job/test_task` from GAE
5. go to GAE's service（`batch-servise`）
6. process and complete

I made each setting assuming the above flow, but the request when creating a task in GAE does not go to `batch-servise`, but goes to default service.
Therefore, the actual processing is as follows.

1. Request to `/job/test_cron` from local machine
2. go to Load balancer
3. go to GAE's servise（`batch-servise`） from Load balancer
4. Create Cloud Task and request `/job/test_task` from GAE
5. go to GAE's servise（**default servise**）
6. process and complete

GAE uses `dispatch.yaml` to direct all requests like `/job/~` to batch-servise.
Therefore, Requesting `/job/test_cron` directly to GAE works as expected.

When using a load balancer, I think that `dispatch.yaml` cannot be used because the IP of GAE is not used. Is this correct?
Also, if anyone else knows how to configure GAE dispatch, it would be very helpful if you could tell me.

Comment: I'm now using `google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue`.
Also, I don't want to update go version.
Is it still possible to choose the destination of the service?

Comment: My go version is ver1.1.1

Comment: I shared my solution. can you have a look at it once?

Answer (score 0):

To override default service you can define [AppEngineRouting](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/AppEngineRouting) which defines routing characteristics specific to App Engine - service, version, and instance.

You can refer this [sample](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks#create_tasks_using_the_client_libraries) which routes to the **default service's**  `/log_payload` endpoint. And update to this:

```
const task = {
  appEngineHttpRequest: {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    relativeUri: '/log_payload',
    appEngineRouting: {
      service: 'batch-servise'
    }
  },
};
```

> When using a load balancer, I think that dispatch.yaml cannot be used because the IP of GAE is not used. Is this correct?

[The load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#load_balancer) does not interfere or interact with routing rules in your dispatch.yaml file. The dispatch.yaml rules are not evaluated until a serverless NEG directs traffic to App Engine.

**Configuring `dispatch.yaml`:**

The root element in the `dispatch.yaml` file is `dispatch`: and contains a list of routing definitions that are specified by the following [subelements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#syntax).
Dispatch rules are order dependent, and only the first rule that matches a URL will be applied.

You may have a look at these [Examples](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#example)

For more information, see [How Requests are Routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#dispatch).

Comment: Thank you for your sharing !
I think this method will work.
However, I set the runtime to `go111`, so I couldn't try this method.
I am now using `google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue` to generate Tasks.

Comment: @Nakasei As [`AppEngineRouting`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/tasks/v2#AppEngineRouting) is supported in the Go language. I believe this will work with [`go`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks#create_tasks_using_the_client_libraries) runtime as well.

Comment: @Nakasei are you still couldn't able to solve issue?

Comment: Yes. I tried it, but I had error regarding go versions.
I can use `AppEngineRouting` with Go if I use `ver1.5` or more.
However I use Go1.1.1 now. So, I'm now investigating how to dispatch with `Go1.1.1`.

Comment: @Nakasei It is always good practice to use the latest versions to experience the latest features and least bugs. As you don’t want to upgrade from `go v1.1.1`, I would recommend you to [target the custom service by overriding the `service` field](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/communicating-between-services) in [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/config/appref#:~:text=and%20app%20elements-,Element,service,-Services%20were%20formerly) file

Comment: OR modifying [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#dispatch) file by providing correct url path and service name.
**Note:** *Dispatch rules are order dependent, and only the first rule that matches a URL will be applied.*